# Simulating Football League Season on R

Tags: r, loops

I have produced code on R which has predicted results of a football league season of 92 teams

```
mod3=glm(formula = Score ~ as.factor(Attack) + as.factor(Defence) + as.factor(Home),     family = poisson,    data = football)
for (i in 1:92){
  for (j in 1:92){
   if (i!=j){
     teamHome=levels(football$Attack)[i] 
     teamAway=levels(football$Attack)[j] 
     homeScore=rpois(1,predict.glm(mod3, data.frame(Attack=teamHome,Defence=teamAway,Home="Y   "),type="response"))
     awayScore=rpois(1,predict.glm(mod3, data.frame(Attack=teamAway,Defence=teamHome,Home="N   "),type="response"))
     Result= if(homeScore>awayScore){
       Result="H"
     } else if(homeScore<awayScore){
       Result="A"
     } else if(homeScore==awayScore){
       Result="D"
     }

     Results<-print(paste(teamHome,homeScore,"      ",teamAway,awayScore,Result),quote=F)
    }
  }
}
```

This produces a list of 8000 0r so matches that I wanted.

However when I do

> teamHome

[1] "Aldershot             "

I only get the first team in my output and when I do

```
   levels(teamHome)

    NULL
```

this is the same for all my variables and is making it difficult to format the results as a 'league table'

Is there any mistake in my code that means I am not getting the full list of "teamHome" or is there a method to access this.

I hope I explained this problem correctly

Thanks

Stephen

Comment: Make sure to use `sample(c("win", "loss"), 14, TRUE,  c(0, 1))` for Buffalo :-(

Comment: Each time through the loop, you are overwriting the values stored in the objects `teamHome`, `teamAway`, `homeScore` and `awayScore`. If each team plays each other team in your simulation, then you could make a matrix, `score`, and replace the two `*Score` lines of your sim with `score[i, j] <- rpois(1, predict.glm(mod3, data.frame(Attack=teamHome,Defence=teamAway,Home="Y   "), type="response"))`. I think.

Comment: The matrix `score` should be 92x92, and after the simulation it should hold the score of each home team (row) vs each away team (col).

Comment: @jbaums thanks for the response but I don't quite understand how this will be done. Can you show we how you would edit my code

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simpler approach to simulating the scores, which takes advantage of the fact that we can predict to multiple new combinations of covariates at once.

First, let's simulate some data to fit the original model:

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 100000
att <- sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE)
def <- sapply(att, function(x) sample(LETTERS[-grep(x, LETTERS)], 1))
X <- data.frame(att, def, home=factor(sample(0:1, n, TRUE)))
mm <- model.matrix(~ ., data=X)
b <- rnorm(ncol(mm), sd=0.1)
mu <- exp(mm %*% b)
y <- rpois(length(mu), mu)
dat <- cbind(y, X)

head(dat)

  y att def home
1 1   G   S    1
2 1   J   S    1
3 1   O   H    1
4 1   X   N    1
5 1   F   W    0
6 2   X   R    1
```

And fit the model:

```
mod <- glm(y ~ ., data=dat, family='poisson')
```

Comparison of `b` and `coef(mod)` indicates that the model estimates the true coefficients relatively accurately (although we needed a large sample size to achieve this, given the many factor levels - and therefore many coefficients - that we are estimating).

Now we can predict the fitted model to some new data. We can use `expand.grid` to return all combinations of an arbitrary number of factors. This is useful if we want to predict to all combinations of attacking team, defending team, and "home".

```
newdat <- setNames(expand.grid(levels(dat$att), levels(dat$def), factor(0:1)),
                   c('att', 'def', 'home'))
# now reduce newdat to exclude rows where att == def
newdat <- subset(newdat, att!=def)

sim.score <- rpois(nrow(newdat), predict(mod, newdat, type='response'))
results <- cbind(newdat, score=sim.score)
head(results)

  att def home score
2   B   A    0     1
3   C   A    0     0
4   D   A    0     2
5   E   A    0     1
6   F   A    0     2
7   G   A    0     0
```

Comment: Thanks for your help this has helped me a lot I am really grateful. Is there however a way I can store the results with a score for both the attack and the def columns. So it is more like a football results list and I don't have to find each combination of att and defend

Comment: I'm not really sure how `home` relates to `att` and `def`. Would the two score columns that you refer to be equivalent to scores corresponding to the two cases: (1) att = team 1, def = team 2, home = TRUE; and (2) att = team 2, def = team 1, home = FALSE?

Comment: yes that would be it so (1) would be home score and (2) would be away score. is there a way of adding this to my model.